# Minimal self-compiling to .pdf Rmarkdown file

Tags: linux, r-markdown

I need to compose a simple rmarkdown file, with text, code and the results of executed code included in a resulting PDF file. I would prefer if the source file is executable and self sifficient, voiding the need for a makefile.

This is the best I have been able to achieve, and it is far from good:

````
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript


library(knitr)
pandoc('hw_ch4.rmd', format='latex')


# TODO: how to NOT print the above commands to the resulting .pdf?
# TODO: how to avoid putting everyting from here on in ""s?
# TODO: how to avoid mentioning the file name above?
# TODO: how to render special symbols, such as tilde, miu, sigma?
#     Unicode character (U+3BC) not set up for use with LaTeX.
#     See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.

# nano hw_ch4.rmd  && ./hw_ch4.rmd && evince hw_ch4.pdf

"
4E1. In the model definition below, which line is the likelihood?
A: y_i is the likelihood, based on the expectation and deviation.


4M1. For the model definition below, simulate observed heights from the prior (not the posterior).
A:
```{r}
points <- 10
rnorm(points, mean=rnorm(points, 0, 10), sd=runif(points, 0, 10))
```


4M3. Translate the map model formula below into a mathematical model definition.
A:
```{r}
flist <- alist(
y tilda dnorm( mu , sigma ),
miu tilda dnorm( 0 , 10 ),
sigma tilda dunif( 0 , 10 )
)
```
"
````

Result:

[image]

Comment: Really? No one?? How do you guys use rmarkdown then? Every single person uses RStudio?

Comment: Using pandoc alone won't run any code chunks. Have you tried using `rmarkdown::render`?

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually came to use is the following header. At first it sounded neat, but later I realized

```
+ is indeed easy to compile in one step
- this is code duplication
- mixing executable script and presentation data in one file is a security risk.
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript


#<!---
library(rmarkdown)
argv <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=FALSE)
fname <- sub("--file=", "", argv[grep("--file=", argv)])
render(fname, output_format="pdf_document")
quit(status=0)
#-->


---
title:
author: 
date: "compiled on: `r Sys.time()`"
---
```

The `quit()` line is supposed to guarantee that the rest of the file is treated as data. The `<!---` and `-->` comments are to render the executable code as comments in the data interpretation. They are, in turn, hidden by the `#`s from the shell.